# Jar signing in eclipse, how to resign after altering source

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt, jar-signing

I had to alter some source in org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode, I used various eclipse plugins as "headless" libraries in a application design to re-factor source code in a specific way.

I only discovered right at the very end that there was a line of code in ASTNode, that makes the application impossible.

The fastest way seemed to be to decompile comment out the line and pack the jar again.
The problem I now have is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException: SHA1 digest error for org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/ASTNode.class
at sun.security.util.ManifestEntryVerifier.verify(ManifestEntryVerifier.java:198)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:212)
at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:199)
```

This application only needs to run once to refactor a large code base.
I'm looking for the quickest solution.

If there is some way to disable the security, in fact there is with a start up argument:

```
startup option -Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
```

this doesn't help me since the libraries are headless. The other possible solution is to resign the jar but I assume a key would be needed or something.

Since it's a disposable application I don't need a clean fix, just anything that is quick.

Answer (score 0):

the way to sign jar is using Java -cp option like below

```
java -cp "jcifs-1.3.17.jar:jespa-1.1.14.jar" jespa.License -u jespa_500_license_SN2136020120531.key
```

Comment: so you can sign it with your own key, not a key that may be related to other libraries or eclipse itself. If I can simple unjar a library change it then, resign it, what good is jar signing as in terms of ant-tamper security devices? I don't really care but I don't wanna waste time on possible dead ends

Comment: you need eclipse key for signing check this out http://wiki.eclipse.org/JAR_Signing